# Extracting url variable in php using $_GET[]

Tags: php, url, variables

I have a simple url and just looking to echo a variable in it and it does not work.

Here is the code

```
<?php    
$name = "mysite";    
echo "<a href= 'BusinessDisplay.php?address = $name'> hello </a>";    
?>

<?php     
echo $_GET['address'];    
?>
```

Comment: Just to make sure - those are in two separate files, right? :)

Comment: BTW: you are producing invalid URL, whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: Remove the spaces around `address = $name`. Your URL should look like `BusinessDisplay.php?address=$name`

Comment: You'd want to encode $name as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That spacing is wrong.

```
"<a href= 'BusinessDisplay.php?address = $name'> hello </a>";
--------------------------------------^-^
```

Comment: $name should be URL encoded as well.

Comment: @Lloyd: Maybe, maybe not. I have no clue what the use case is :)

Comment: Wasn't picking on your answer just a hint for others :)